# CSS to push content down page

Tags: css

On a web page I'm working on I have a fixed #top section containing the nav which is causing the content below to partially hide behind it.

The page is this: http://s361608839.websitehome.co.uk/pt-build/templatebuild/

I've tried adding margin-top to #slider and margin-bottom to #top to try and push each other apart but none of those have worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just change

```
div.anythingSlider {
  position: relative;
  padding: 110px 350px 28px 45px;
}
```

I changed the top padding from 0 to 110px

Comment: This is not a smart solution because if he were to add another page / change the page to remove `anythingSlider` he would have to add the `padding` to the element that is newly on top. It's better to solve the problem from `#top`.

Comment: @kokos, it is all relative. We do not know what the plan for the site is. I agree that there are many solutions to it, but it depends on the overall site. If all pages have the fixed navigation, i would add the padding to the body.

Answer (score 2):

Your `#top` is `fixed`, so the margins won't work.

You have to do two things to fix this problem:

1. Give your `body` a `padding-top` or `margin-top` equal to the height of `#top` (151px)
2. Give `#top` a `top:0;` so it still sticks to the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
div.anythingSlider{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

`top: 50%` will shift your content down while `translateY` will put it back in place.

Answer (score 0):

just add `top: 0;` to `#topwrap` and `margin-top: 100px` to `body`. (replace 100px with a value you like, 100px is the minimum to see the first heading, but your `#topwrap` is 151px tall - just try wich looks best)

Answer (score -1):

Use padding-top:150px; on the div with class anythingSlider

Comment: ... and if the site gets reordered, everything breaks again - isn't it better to solve this by changing `#topwrap` like Kokos and me mentioned?

Comment: The downrating is pretty dickish given you don't know the layout of the site.  If any page on the site does NOT have the header then body margin is clearly the wrong way to do it.  I, for one, do not advocate changing the layout of every page on the site unless I know what every page on the site looks like.